# How to change this into a while loop in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, ghci

Haskell is challenging!  What I figured out so far is that I can do the following to simulate a for-loop in Haskell to get a list of numbers from the user:

```hs
myList <- sequence [putStr "Enter an integer: " >> (
    \s -> read s :: Int) <$> getLine | t <- [1..5]]
```

Great!  So `myList` contains five integers that I have entered.  Great!  But here's the catch.  Instead of a for-loop that iterates five times (or any finite number of times) how can I convert the above to the equivalent while-loop?

So what I'm thinking of is this, but it won't work, unfortunately.  Is there some "magic" way to make it work?

```hs
takeWhile (\x -> x > 0) $ sequence [putStr "Enter an integer: " >> (
    \s -> read s :: Int) <$> getLine | t <- [1..]]
```

The problem is that `(\x -> x > 0)` works with Ints.  (Or any Num type.)  But what's coming from that list is really a bunch of IO Ints.  `x > 0` returns a Bool.  I need a function that returns an IO Bool?  I'm a little lost.  Can someone point the way to Haskell enlightenment for me?!  Studying this on my own isn't exactly easy!!!  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: That magic is called [`forever`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forever)!

Comment: Also I don't know if you noticed, but your code snippets don't compile.

Comment: It's hard to see how `forever` could ever yield something that acts like a while loop.

Comment: @amalloy I was thinking of `while(true)`... :facepalm:

Comment: The first code snippet DOES compile!  Unless there's a typo in there, but trust me, I tested it several times and it compiles.  The second code snippet, with "takeWhile" however, does not compile, but I just wanted people to get an idea of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot write this program with a `sequence` of an infinite list of IO actions. Any operations you perform "outside" of the sequence will be unable to inspect its contents, and any operations inside the sequence will be unable to stop it from continuing.

Instead, you must write an IO action which reads an Int, inspects it, and decides whether to continue or to stop at that time.

```
positiveInts :: IO [Int]
positiveInts = do
  putStr "Enter an integer: "
  i <- readLn
  if i <= 0
    then pure []
    else (i:) <$> positiveInts
```

Answer (score 0):

@amalloy's answer is great. It's *kind of* conditional sequencing.

Perhaps we may attempt generalizing it further by inventing `takeWhileM` (basically conditional sequencing) which sequences only an initial part of an indefinitely long list of actions while a predicate satisfies.

```
takeWhileM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> [m a] -> m [a]
takeWhileM f (a:as) = a >>= \n -> if f n then (n:) <$> takeWhileM f as
                                         else pure []
```

So for this particular case i run it like

```
λ> takeWhileM (> 0) . repeat $ putStr "Enter an integer:" >> readLn
Enter an integer:1
Enter an integer:2
Enter an integer:3
Enter an integer:4
Enter an integer:5
Enter an integer:0
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: This isn't what I'd expect a function named `takeWhileM` to do. The one in `monad-loops` has type `Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]`, which better fits with functions like `filterM` or `mapM`.

Comment: @amalloy Yes.. you are possibly right.. we may perhaps call this function `sequenceWhile` for a better naming convention.

Comment: Hey there @amalloy, wow!  Thanks so much!!!!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Is Haskell your primary language?  I'm still at the dabbler stage.  I think Haskell is really interesting, and I want to continue working with it, but not sure if I'll ever reach any high level or professional level of skill in the language.  Maybe?  Could be Nothing or Just success!!!  Hahahaha.  Just an FP joke.  Okay, thanks again.  This was super helpful, and your takeWhileM function was not hard to read.  By the way, can you recommend any resources for Haskell wannabes who are not geniuses?

Comment: @amalloy I have just discovered that it was needless to rediscover `sequenceWhile` since it already lives in [Control.Monad.Extra](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-extras-0.6.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Extra.html#sequenceWhile) which fits the job like a glove. So yes.. it should be called `squenceWhile`. :)

Comment: @Douglas Lewitt I believe you address me... As @amalloy mentions this function should not be called `takeWhileM` since by convention that name fits to another type signature as mentioned in his above comment. This function should be called `sequenceWhile` instead. Don't let Haskell intimidate you. Once you (can) forget about what you know about programming Haskell starts making so much sense. All you need is time so never give up. [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Redu, thanks. I try to be persistent!  I think I have a rough understanding of Monads.  They are essentially a context for a type.  So you have for example Ints, but then there's the Maybe Int, the IO Int, the Either Int, the List Int or [Int], etc, and it seems that a lot of Haskell is devoted to building functions that act upon the type that is contained within the context or Monad.  For example, 2 * 3 = 6, simple!  But what about multiplying (Just 2) and (Just 3)?   So that's pure (\x y -> x*y)  <*> (Just 2) <*> (Just 3).  But why would we want to do that in a language in the first place?

Comment: @Douglas Lewit I think you mean `(*) <$> (Just 2) <*> (Just 3)`. That's functors, applicatives instead of monad. There is also a function monad which mostly manifests itself as the Reader monad. A function is also a Monad since it (the context) harbors a value to be revealed inside (the value that it returns) once applied by a parameter. It can be a pure value or another function (since functions in Haskell are curried). These contexts can take many shapes like f.i. the Probability Monad. See [Probabilistic Functional Programming in Haskell](https://www.kisa.link/N4KS) . Once it clicks.! :)